# which rectangle line hits first

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry

I have a list of rectangles stored as two cardinal points etc. `[[5,10],[10,15]]`, and I know that they all intersect with a line from one point to another. How to find which rectangle intersects with a line first?

Comment: The one that absolute difference between the `x` coordinate of the line's start point and its lower `x` coordinate is lowest.

Comment: kind of, but what if line goes backwards, or upwards

Comment: That all depends on what you mean by first and what'd be the center of your coordinate system, besides lines don't have a direction. Also, in case the difference for two rectangle is equal like when the rectangles are vertically sorted and the lines goes vertically as well, you can check the difference between `y`s.

Comment: @Kasramvd They do in this case, the question is about a segment from point A to point B, and the question is what rectangle intersects with the segment at the closest position to A.

Comment: I assume that the question asks for a better algorithm that just intersecting with every rectangle and pick the closest point to the beginning of the line.

Comment: A line can go backwards? You mean a vector? Or more precisely, a point moving along a vector?

Comment: @jdehesa you understood me corectly

Comment: @PhamTrung we can call that line vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line (defined by two points) has parametric equation

```
X = X0 + t * (X1 - X0)
Y = Y0 + t * (Y1 - Y0)
```

Substitute left or right (depending on line direction) rectangle edge coordinates in the first equation, top or right coordinates - in the second equation and find the least value of parameter `t` that provides intersection with edge.

For example, get `tl` value for left edge of rectangle from the first equation. Find `Y` for this `tl` value from the second equation and check whether this `Y` lies in `top..bottom` range.

Do you have additional limitations/information about rectangle positions and sizes? Is rectangle set constant and you use many lines? Or line is constant and there are some sets of rectangles?

Comment: Was about to write that. Just note that one needs to be careful if `X1 - X0` or `Y1 - Y0` are zero or very close to zero (vertical and horizontal lines). Besides that, I _think_ that if rectangles do not overlap the one with a corner closest to the first point is the winner, but I'm not completely sure. Although since these are axis-aligned rectangles just finding the intersection is probably faster.